# Image browser and upload button not show in ck editior in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Image browser and upload button not show in ck editior in asp.net mvc please provide any solution.

I used that below link..

http://amitraya.blogspot.in/2014/09/ck-editor-implement-your-own-image.html

I used step by step in according to provide this link solution but not show image upload browser and upload button in ckeditior . please check problem of my code and given link..

image 1
[image]

Image 2[image]

Comment: Please post the code which does not work

Comment: Please check link, i have already provide link.i used same step by step.

Comment: It's better if you post your code, specifically the bit which is supposed to render the upload button. Most people won't bother to read some blog post and then guess what mistake either you or the author of the post might have made.

Comment: ck editiot version use 4.5.6 statndard version lot of file include in simple assigment..

Comment: only add ckeditior in mvc solution and create index.cshtml code @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   // Layout = "~Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Index</h2>
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1" style ="width:200px;" rows="10"> sample text</textarea>

Comment: then run application